# Need 6 tabs in tab bar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am implementing a tab bar based application and i need 6 tabs in the tab bar,but the tab bar is displaying only 4 tabs and in Fifth tab it is displaying More with 5th tab and 6th tab in table view.

Can i have 6 tabs in tab bar without More tab?

Comment: I dont think its duplicate. The question mentioned here is far away than the notified question.

Answer (score 13):

Maximum is 5 Tabs in a tabbar. This is because when there was more than 5 tab, they would be too small and for people with thicker fingers it would be difficult to hit the wanted tab.

If you really want, you can write your own tabbar-controller that allows 6 or even more tabs, but you should not do that. The chance is high, apple will reject your app because it doesn't meet apples design-rules. And I think it is good, that apple rejects such apps!

Comment: Ok, then i will go with More tab, i will keep More tab in the app, No problem and thank you

Comment: iPhone 3/4/5 allow 5 options which would make the tab bar buttons 64 points wide (320 / 5). The iPhone 6+ having 6 buttons would make each button 69 points wide (414 / 6). So this can't just be about button width.

Comment: @cncool: Not the number of pixels is important. The with on screen in mm is important. Your fingers don't know pixels. But they easily can tab on a 10 mm wide rectangle. The screens of iPhone 3, 4, and 5 are 49 mm wide (portrait). Divided into 5 tabs gives about 10 mm per tab. The screen of iPhone 6 is in portrait mode 58 mm. If you divide this width into 6 tabs, then again each tab is about 10 mm wide.  The width of the screen of iPhone 6+ is 68 mm, which gives a tab-width of about 11 mm when divided into 6 tabs. So in all cases you have a tab-width of about 10 or 11 mm.

Comment: Facebook iOS has 6 tabs now. I came here because I was searching how people would implement a 6 tab-tabBar. Probably they're not doing the 6 tabs in iPhone5/5s sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your custom tab bar controller for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have 6 tabs in tab bar without More tab. After adding 4 tabs, in Fifth tab it will display More with 5th tab and 6th tab and it is the characteristics of tab bar in iOS. You can try toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this thing but you need to use customview.

your tabbar works in back-ground and place a custom view at bottom in window and set delegate for it and add this view in main window.

then you will hit button at bottom and you can redirect event to appDelegate class by delegate.

where you can set your desired tab as by button hit.

i think you may get some ideas.