# tab bar controller with 4 tabs and one button

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a `Tab Bar` controller. It has 4 tabs. I now want to place a `Button` which would take place as the 5th tab. Clicking the button should perform some action (i.e. log something)

Here is a image of what i am trying to do. The last tab is supposed to be a button and not a Tab Bar View Controller. Is this possible to do?

Saw this link but not sure if its what i am looking for. [link](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per apple guidelines when you add more then 5 tabs the 5th tab will auto named as More; this because of the use interaction and focus of touch. And not recommend to have more than 5 tabs when you go with custom implementation. This is because there are chance of rejections when you submit the app to App Store.

For your reference here is the same question by other user [5th tab to be a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964239/need-6-tabs-in-tab-bar)

Comment: this has nothing to do with more than 5 tabs. I want 4 tabs and one button.

Comment: Then in that case you have to go with custom implementation only by creating tab bar kind and handling it your own way. For your reference you can look at this sample project http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-custom-tabbar-storyboard/. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Apple's iOS SDK has such way to approach. I really recommend you to check out some customized design like

[KYGooeyMenu](https://github.com/KittenYang/KYGooeyMenu)

If you think that's what you want, you can integrate it into your project.